Installation problem with fbprophet on WIndows 11
I'm trying to install fbprophet for a simulation model on my system but keep getting the same error and am using command prompt for installation. I also have jupyter notebooks on my sytem. The error code alongwith the installation for the same is provided in the runtime code of the terminal below. Please ignore lines after this point as i'm trying to fulfill the word limit for uploading my question.The library is required for a weather simulation code that will be used at our sites of construction requiring smooth construction provess while improving the overall planning and mitigatig the effect of the incoming monsoon.
C:\Users\user2>pip install fbprophet
Collecting fbprophet
  Using cached fbprophet-0.7.1.tar.gz (64 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.22 in c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (3.0.10)
Collecting cmdstanpy==0.9.5 (from fbprophet)
  Using cached cmdstanpy-0.9.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
Collecting pystan>=2.14 (from fbprophet)
  Using cached pystan-3.9.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.4 in c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.2.2)
Collecting matplotlib>=2.0.0 (from fbprophet)
  Using cached matplotlib-3.9.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting LunarCalendar>=0.0.9 (from fbprophet)
  Using cached LunarCalendar-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
Collecting convertdate>=2.1.2 (from fbprophet)
  Using cached convertdate-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.3 kB)
Collecting holidays>=0.10.2 (from fbprophet)
  Using cached holidays-0.49-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (23 kB)
Collecting setuptools-git>=1.2 (from fbprophet)
  Using cached setuptools_git-1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.0 in c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.9.0.post0)
Collecting tqdm>=4.36.1 (from fbprophet)
  Using cached tqdm-4.66.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (57 kB)
Collecting pymeeus<=1,>=0.3.13 (from convertdate>=2.1.2->fbprophet)
  Using cached PyMeeus-0.5.12.tar.gz (5.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting ephem>=3.7.5.3 (from LunarCalendar>=0.0.9->fbprophet)
  Using cached ephem-4.1.5-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (6.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from LunarCalendar>=0.0.9->fbprophet) (2024.1)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet)
  Using cached contourpy-1.2.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet)
  Using cached cycler-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0 (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet)
  Using cached fonttools-4.52.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (164 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.3.1 (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet)
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (6.5 kB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0 (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet)
  Using cached packaging-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
Collecting pillow>=8 (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet)
  Using cached pillow-10.3.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (9.4 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.3.1 (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet)
  Using cached pyparsing-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.7 in c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.0.4->fbprophet) (2024.1)
Collecting aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6 (from pystan>=2.14->fbprophet)
  Using cached aiohttp-3.9.5-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (7.7 kB)
Collecting clikit<0.7,>=0.6 (from pystan>=2.14->fbprophet)
  Using cached clikit-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pystan to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting pystan>=2.14 (from fbprophet)
  Using cached pystan-3.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.8.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
INFO: pip is still looking at multiple versions of pystan to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached pystan-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. See https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking for guidance. If you want to abort this run, press Ctrl + C.
  Using cached pystan-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
  Using cached pystan-2.19.1.1.tar.gz (16.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-941ls65v\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-941ls65v\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-941ls65v\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-941ls65v\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 122, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


I also faced the same problem and got it resolved after installing the Microsoft C++ build tools 14.0 or greater. You can also use the following link:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
Then:
pip install cython

Then:
pip install fbprophet

